# Article page in Drupal

Tags: nodes

Usually the articles in a drupal installation are published on the front page, but what I would like to do is to create a menu link to show all articles (instead of the front page)?

Comment: It appears you are new to stackexchange, please select an answer to your question by pressing on the check next to the answer. More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: If my answer was useful, please choose it as the official answer to the question by clicking on the check icon next to the up/down voting widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

With Views you can make highly customizable lists of content. I suggest you use Drupal 7 and Views 3, because its easier to make a View in it than in the version 2. If you are using Drupal 6 try [Simpleviews](http://drupal.org/project/simpleviews), which will let you create Views very easily too.

I make this suggestions because as a newcomer the full Views interface can be a bit daunting. Have a play around and good luck!